# Insert rows that add other rows-values in pandas dataframe aggregating values in python/pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have four columns: [Set, Subset, Cardinality, Index]

This could be something like:

```
[A, AB, 5, 1]
[A, AC, 8, 1]
[A, AD, 7, 1]
[A, AB, 5, 2]
[A, AC, 9, 2]
[A, AD, 1, 2]
[A, AB, 3, 3]
[A, AC, 5, 3]
[A, AD, 2, 3]
```

I want to add new rows that add all the subsets cardinality for the same set and index and get:

```
[A, AB, 5, 1]
[A, AC, 8, 1]
[A, AD, 7, 1]
[A, null, 20, 1]
[A, AB, 5, 2]
[A, AC, 9, 2]
[A, AD, 1, 2]
[A, null, 15, 2]
[A, AB, 3, 3]
[A, AC, 5, 3]
[A, AD, 2, 3]
[A, null, 10, 3]
```

where the added rows aggregate the cardinality for the same "Set" and "Index"

Answer (score 1):

Using pandas DataFrames you can do:

```py
cols=['Set', 'Subset', 'Cardinality', 'Index']
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'AB', 5, 1],
                   ['A', 'AC', 8, 1],
                   ['A','AD', 7, 1],
                   ['A', 'AB', 5, 2],
                   ['A', 'AC', 9, 2],
                   ['A', 'AD', 1, 2],
                   ['A', 'AB', 3, 3],
                   ['A', 'AC', 5, 3],
                   ['A', 'AD', 2, 3]],
                  columns = cols)

tmp = df.groupby(['Set', 'Index']).sum().reset_index()
df = pd.concat([df, tmp], axis=0)[cols]
df
  Set Subset  Cardinality  Index
0   A     AB            5      1
1   A     AC            8      1
2   A     AD            7      1
3   A     AB            5      2
4   A     AC            9      2
5   A     AD            1      2
6   A     AB            3      3
7   A     AC            5      3
8   A     AD            2      3
0   A    NaN           20      1
1   A    NaN           15      2
2   A    NaN           10      3
```

Comment: Perfect. What if there are columns, like "Position", and I want them to be null like Subset. I only want to sum on Cardinality.

Comment: Use the same code with selecting the feature to sum in the groupby: `tmp = df.groupby(['Set', 'Index'])['Cardinality'].sum().reset_index()`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GroupBy.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) and [`DataFrame.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) with [`DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) to sort:

```
(df.append(df.groupby(['Set', 'Index'], as_index=False).sum())
   .sort_values(['Index','Set', 'Subset']))
```

---

**Output**

```
  Set  Subset   Cardinality   Index
0   A      AB             5       1
1   A      AC             8       1
2   A      AD             7       1
0   A     NaN            20       1
3   A      AB             5       2
4   A      AC             9       2
5   A      AD             1       2
1   A     NaN            15       2
6   A      AB             3       3
7   A      AC             5       3
8   A      AD             2       3
2   A     NaN            10       3
```

Comment: Thank you. The sort_values is a nice touch.

Comment: you are welcome, sorry I understood late what you were looking for :)